# Polymer Animation Work in Firefox not Chromium

Tags: chromium, polymer-1.0

I am using Polymer 1.0 animations through the use of neon-animated-pages and they seem to be working in Firefox (v38, Ubuntu Linux 14.04) as expected.  In Chromium (v43), there is no attempt to animate (just a straight swap from one page to another).  If I try and use the [neon-animated-pages Demo](https://elements.polymer-project.org/elements/neon-animation?view=demo:demo/index.html&active=neon-animated-pages) in the Polymer Catalog, they work fine in the same instance of Chromium.

Any tips on what I am maybe doing wrong?

Comment: Just realised I am on Chrome v43 - Version 43.0.2357.81 Ubuntu 14.04 (64-bit).  Updated question accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Just did a bower update and v1.0.7 of most polymer elements got sucked down and the issue seems to be resolved.

Looking at the install list, neon-animation#1.0.6 is probably the corrected element.